# What is the average center of six points in space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I have three pairs of points in 3D space. These may or may not be coplanar. I want to find a point such that it is equidistant from each pair of points. I know that may or may not be possible depending on the positions of the points. What I want is the best average point, which I can take safely as the centre and draw a sphere from there whose radius is the maximum distance of this point from any of the six points, then I want all the points to remain inside the sphere.

Comment: Your question would probably be more appropriate at MO's sister site math.stackexchange.com. This site is for research-level questions, in mathematics itself. 'Research-level' means, roughly, questions that might be discussed between two professors, or between graduate students working on PhD's.

Comment: If you mean that research-level means questions can be asked only by research students or professors then please note that I do have a Masters in Mathematics. Right now I am involved in computer graphics, and this question relates to that. Thanks for the reference to the site, I appeciate.

Comment: Alok - no, I mean that there are plenty of very interesting questions with some mathematical content that are not suitable for MO.  I think this is one of them.

Comment: @Henry : I agree absolutely, I went to the site and it is quite interesting as well as engaging. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distance from a pair of points instead of from each one of a pair of points does not seem to be well defined.  However, you could simply take the centroid of all six points (add the coordinates and divide by 6 in each axis), then compute the distance to each of the six points, and use the maximum for the radius of the sphere.  It is not clear how you want us to use the fact that the points come in pairs instead of six single points.

Comment: As I read it, "equidistant from each pair of points" means that if the pairs are p_{1,1}, p_{1,2}, p_{2,1}, p_{2,2}, p_{3,1}, p_{3,2} then we want |p - p_{i,1}| = |p - p_{i,2}| for each i.

Comment: Thanks, that partially do answer my question. In fact I have tried the centroid approach before and it seems to work but I was not sure it is the most suitable candidate. As for the pair of points, what I actually have in each pair are points which are maximum and minimum from the origin(0,0,0) in x,y and z axis. For example, the points two points in x - pair will have their x coordinate, minimum and maximum, the y and z coord of these two points are arbitrary.

Comment: If Qiaochu's interpretaion is right, each of these equidistance
conditions defines a plane, and generically three planes
meet in a unique point. I'm not sure how this squares with
Alok's final sentence about the "best" point and spheres
which seem to be looking for something like
the point whose greatest distance from the given points is minimized.

Comment: I think what Robin says"and generically three planes meet in a unique point." is exactly the solution I want.

Comment: @Alok I'm still not clear on the pairs of points.  Is one pair $(x_{min},y,z) \text{and} (x_{max},y,z)$ with the same $y$ and $z$?  The sense would be that you really want the whole segment to be in the sphere.  That is OK as the sphere is convex.  Could you give an example of three pairs?

Comment: @Ross : Well, the three pairs are such that for each pair one of the coordinates is maximum and minimum for all the six points, the rest two of the coordinated are different. An example would be  :

pair 1 >> xMax: (72, 22, -201), xMin: (-209, -24, 6)
pair 2 >> yMax: (64, 71, -193), yMin: (-179, -88, -53)
pair 3 >> zMax: (-194, -76, 36), zMin: (8, 12, -210)

Comment: @Alok I don't see anything special about breaking the points into pairs then.  I think just using the centroid and maximum radius is pretty good.  If you want to reduce the radius, there may be a better point for the center, but I don't know how to find it without using a multidimensional minimizer on the max distance.  It should converge quickly as you have a pretty good start and well behaved function.

Answer (score -1):

You want mini ball.

http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/miniball.html